# how to resize page automatically while resizing the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have used absolute positioning in most of the element in my div. but when i resize the window some elements hide. Can't it be possible to resize the page automatically when i resize the window without changing absolute positioning ???
using something `window.onresize()`

Comment: Absolute positioning is often a poor layout method...it's very inflexible as you have found. There are much better options available: [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: You need to show a snippet of your problem before anyone can really help you with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could do easily using some css framework, like bootstrap wich could provide an all in one solution, isn perfect but is easy to learn and undestand

Answer (score 0):

You want to make it responsive. To do that you should look in to how to style your elements relatively to the browser window. This is done by changing your `px` values with `%` and `ems` (relative values).

Also later you can set `media queries`. These are styles that only apply when a particular statement evaluates, like:

```
@media screen (max-width:500px) {
    /* Styles here only apply if the browser window has min-width 500px */
}
```

Here are some links to read up on: [Responsive Web Design Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/index?hl=en), [Responsive Web Design: What It Is and How To Use It](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)

Comment: Actually, changing px values to % or ems may not be necessary, especially if you use media queries. Sometimes, you intentionally want px for good reason.